# Count points inside polygons using R

Tags: r, spatial-join, sf, point-in-polygon

I have imported two shapefiles in R, one with polygons and other with points. Each polygon has an identifier different from the others, and each point also.

The polygons and points identifiers are not related to each other, in fact the polygon id is a text and the point id is a number.

I need the polygon SF object to have a **new column with the number of points inside it**.

I have made several tests but none of them work well.

Comment: Please add more information about your data (e.g. CRS). Also, because this is a `R` related question try to include the code and where the error occurs. If possible, using the `dput` function, share a small subset of your dataset. In this way, you will help others to replicate the issue and it's more likely to help you. The way your question is currently written, we can only make guesses.

Comment: I use WGS84.

points_in_polygons <- st_within(pt2, gr) #gr is grid of polygons
p = as.data.frame(points_in_polygons)
points_count <- p %>%  group_by(col.id) %>%  summarize(points_count = n())

And I have lost the identifier CODEPOLYGON in the process, so i cant merge or left join

Comment: It would be better if you could edit your question and include the complete code as well as a sample of your dataset (using the `dput` function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lenghts()` of `st_intersects(gr, points_in_polygons)`. A generic example with 10x10 grid and sampled points might look like this:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(3)
# example grid
grid_sf <- st_bbox(c(xmin = 0, ymin = 0, xmax = 10, ymax = 10)) |>
  st_make_grid() |>
  st_sf(geometry = _)

# example points
points_sf <- st_sample(grid_sf, size = 200)
points_sf
#> Geometry set for 200 features 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.08566967 ymin: 0.07912433 xmax: 9.93222 ymax: 9.970992
#> CRS:           NA
#> First 5 geometries:
#> POINT (1.680415 7.314981)
#> POINT (8.075164 8.604901)
#> POINT (3.849424 3.427103)
#> POINT (3.277343 4.929222)
#> POINT (6.021007 8.538533)

grid_sf$point_count <- st_intersects(grid_sf, points_sf) |> lengths()
```

`sf`object with point counts:

```r
grid_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
#> CRS:           NA
#> First 10 features:
#>                          geometry point_count
#> 1  POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 ...           1
#> 2  POLYGON ((1 0, 2 0, 2 1, 1 ...           5
#> 3  POLYGON ((2 0, 3 0, 3 1, 2 ...           1
#> 4  POLYGON ((3 0, 4 0, 4 1, 3 ...           1
#> 5  POLYGON ((4 0, 5 0, 5 1, 4 ...           2
#> 6  POLYGON ((5 0, 6 0, 6 1, 5 ...           3
#> 7  POLYGON ((6 0, 7 0, 7 1, 6 ...           3
#> 8  POLYGON ((7 0, 8 0, 8 1, 7 ...           3
#> 9  POLYGON ((8 0, 9 0, 9 1, 8 ...           3
#> 10 POLYGON ((9 0, 10 0, 10 1, ...           1

ggplot(grid_sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = point_count), alpha = .4) +
  geom_sf(data = points_sf) +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = point_count), alpha = .6) +
  scale_fill_viridis_b() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>